# HBase read/write using pyspark

Tags: python, hbase, pyspark

I am trying to read and write from hbase using pyspark.

Code

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import json

sc = SparkContext(appName="HBaseInputFormat")
host = "localhost"
table = "posts"
conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": "localhost", "hbase.mapreduce.inputtable": "posts"}
keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter"
valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter"

def save_record(rdd):
    keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringToImmutableBytesWritableConverter"
    valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringListToPutConverter"
    conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": "localhost",
            "hbase.mapred.outputtable": "xxxx19",
            "mapreduce.outputformat.class":
            "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat",
            "mapreduce.job.output.key.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
            "mapreduce.job.output.value.class": "org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable"}
    row_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x.split("\n")[0])
    datamap = row_rdd.map(lambda x: (str(json.loads(x)["row"]), [str(json.loads(x)["row"]), "p", "cats_json", "lolva"]))
    datamap.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf=conf, keyConverter=keyConv, valueConverter=valueConv)

hbase_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",
        keyConverter=keyConv,
        valueConverter=valueConv,
        conf=conf)

message_rdd = hbase_rdd.map(lambda x:x[1]) # message_rdd = hbase_rdd.map(lambda x:x[0]) will give only row-key
save_record(message_rdd)
messages = message_rdd.take(1)
```

Exception

```
17/02/02 16:02:25 INFO mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase: Input split length: 187 M bytes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 157, in manager
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 61, in worker
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 136, in main
    if read_int(infile) == SpecialLengths.END_OF_STREAM:
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 545, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
17/02/02 16:02:26 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify table name
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.setConf(TableOutputFormat.java:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1099)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/02/02 16:02:26 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3, localhost): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify table name
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.setConf(TableOutputFormat.java:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1099)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/02/02 16:02:26 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
17/02/02 16:02:26 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 2
17/02/02 16:02:26 INFO executor.Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
17/02/02 16:02:26 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 2 was cancelled
17/02/02 16:02:26 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 2 (saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset at PythonRDD.scala:804) failed in 0.908 s
17/02/02 16:02:26 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 2 failed: saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset at PythonRDD.scala:804, took 0.977607 s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sahil/Desktop/Relation_Extraction/pyspark_test.py", line 33, in <module>
    save_record(message_rdd)
  File "/home/sahil/Desktop/Relation_Extraction/pyspark_test.py", line 22, in save_record
    datamap.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf=conf1, keyConverter=keyConv, valueConverter=valueConv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1346, in saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaErrorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 157, in manager
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 61, in worker
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 136, in main
    if read_int(infile) == SpecialLengths.END_OF_STREAM:
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 545, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
17/02/02 16:02:26 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify table name
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.setConf(TableOutputFormat.java:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1099)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/02/02 16:02:26 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2) on executor localhost: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (Must specify table name) [duplicate 1]
17/02/02 16:02:26 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 2.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3, localhost): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify table name
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.setConf(TableOutputFormat.java:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1099)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1922)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1074)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1074)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1074)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.saveAsHadoopDataset(PythonRDD.scala:804)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify table name
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.setConf(TableOutputFormat.java:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1099)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
```

As we can see that, I have mentioned the output table name as **xxxx19**, the error regarding **Must specify table name** looks daunting.
Any help will be welcomed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A random guess is that RDD uses conf values that were given during creation. Try to add  "hbase.mapred.outputtable": "xxxx19" to first conf object and let's see if it helps

Comment: It did not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working by adding the following jars while running spark-submit

1. spark-examples-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar
2. hbase-examples-0.98.19-hadoop2.jar

Complete command

```
spark-submit --jars lib/spark-examples-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar,/usr/local/Hbase/lib/hbase-examples-0.98.19-hadoop2.jar ~/Desktop/Relation_Extraction/pyspark_test.py
```

Comment: that's really strange

Comment: Yes, it is. However the error  EOF serialization stil persists, although the data gets written to HBase. Any thoughts?

Comment: is written data corrupted or not?

Comment: No the data is fine. I guess I need to serialise the data before writing.

Answer (score 0):

set in conf object

```
TableOutputFormat."hbase.mapred.outputtable", "username:tableName"
```

Comment: conf[TableOutputFormat."hbase.mapred.outputtable"] = "xxxx19"
Do you mean like this?